# prove two series are convergent or divergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series, factorial

I was studying Random Walks and derived these two series.

Let $p\in (0,1)\setminus \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, i.e. $p\in (0,\frac{1}{2})\cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1).$

I want to prove the following series is convergent, i.e.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k!}{k!k!} p^k(1-p)^k < \infty$$

Meanwhile, I also want to prove the following series is divergent, i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k!}{k!k!} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2k} = \infty$$

I have no idea of dealing with the fraction of factorials. What I have observed so far is just that, $p^k(1-p)^k < (\frac{1}{2})^{2k}\,$ for any $p\in (0,\frac{1}{2})\cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1),$ which makes sense of the divergence and convergence of the two series above.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the d'Alembert's rule since the general term is highly multiplicative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: @Lelouch Thanks for reminding me of the ratio test. I have done the ratio test which can really prove the convergence of the $p$-related series. But for the $2$-related series, ratio test is inconclusive in that the limit of the ratio is $1$.

Comment: Your two expressions are the expected number of returns to the start.  If $p=\frac12$ a balanced one-dimensional random walk is likely to do this infinitely often, but otherwise it is likely to drift off in the appropriate direction and so only visit the start a finite number of times

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment. Yea, I understand this point of view from probability theory(and actually I derived these two series exactly from your observation). I just want a rigorous analytical proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use Stirling's approximation:
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n
$$
to arrive at (writing $q:=1-p$)
$$
\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}(pq)^k \sim \frac {(4pq)^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick hint. Yea, with this approximation we can easily establish the desired convergence and divergence of the two series.